# Cannot Exit Method after throwing Exception

Tags: c++, exception, throw

Be warned, I don't really understand how throw works. Right now I have a method that checks if one variable is greater than or equal to another variable and if it isn't then it throws a string exception.

The problem is I don't know how to exit out of the method after the exception is thrown without getting an unhandled exception error.

```cpp
CircleSquare Square::operator+ (const Circle& op2)
{
    /// Variables
    CircleSquare ret;

    /// Sets the temporary Square object's characteristics to LHS's colour, the sum of LHS sideLength + RHS sideLength, and Square name
    ret.SetName((char *)"Square-Circle");
    ret.SetColour((char *)this->GetColour());

    if (sideLength >= (op2.GetRadius() * 2))
    {
        ret.SetSideLength(sideLength);
    }
    else
    {
        throw ("The sideLength of square is smaller than the diameter of the contained circle.");
        return ret; // <--- Here is where the error occurs
    }

    if ((op2.GetRadius() * 2) <= sideLength && op2.GetRadius() >= 0.0)
    {
        ret.SetRadius(op2.GetRadius());
    }
    else
    {
        throw ("The radius of contained circle is larger than the sideLength of the square.");
        return ret;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

What I want it to do is to throw the exception and then I exit out of the method and handle the exception in my try-catch block, but instead, it comes up with the "Unhandled Exception" at the `return ret;`

How can I exit out of this method without getting the error?

Comment: [mcve] would be helpful.  The `return` doesn't happen, because the `throw` unwound the sack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `catch` what you're `throw`ing. Also, the `return` statement never happends when you `throw`. (You should delete the line that says:

```
return ret; // <--- Here is where the error occurs
```

Most likely, you'll see some warning of the compiler about that (that's code that is never going to be executed). Your code should compile without warings. Always. (`-Werror` compile flag is very good for this).

`throw` means: *return but not the normal way*

You need to do something like:

```
try {
    Square a;
    Circle b;
    CircleSquare sum= a + b; // You try to sum
    // If you can, the return statement will give a value to sum
    // If you throw, sum will not get constructed, 
    // b and a will be destroyed and the catch 
    // will be executed instead of anything below
    // the call to operator+
    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
} catch (std::string s) {
    // Will only catch exceptions of type std::string
    std::cerr << "Error: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

It is "like" if you did a `goto` to the `catch` block, but cleaning everything.

If you don't handle it, it will still terminate every function abnormally until it finds a `catch` block of the right type or until it exites `main`.